# How to properly set a baseurl on localhost

Tags: php, base-url

I have a php file **verify.php** in a folder called **emailtest** on localhost. I'm implementing an email verification script. But i'm having issues with the activation url that is emailed after registration. Take a look:

```
define("BASE_PATH", dirname('http://localhost:8888/'))

$url = BASE_PATH . '/emailtest'.'/verify.php?email=' . urlencode($email) . "&key=$encode";
```

In the email sent, i'm getting a link that looks like this(which is unopenable):

```
    `"http:/emailtest/verify.php?email=lexon4ril%40yahoo.com&key=58a9a..."`
```

But what i really want is this

```
`http:localhost:8888/emailtest/verify.php?email=lexon4ril%40yahoo.com&key=58a9a...`
```

How can i properly set the url.?

**UPDATE**
Just for future reference i mistyped the link, should be:

```
`http://localhost:8888//emailtest/verify.php?email=lexon4ril%40yahoo.com&key=58a9a...`
```

Comment: You have: `http:localhost:8888` in your question.. is that what you really want?

Comment: Show us the real code

Comment: i somehow have the feeling your `BASE_PATH` constant is not being taken into account for some reason... i don't think this has anything to do with it being used on localhost or on a hosted server - have you tried to upload it somewhere and test it that way?

Comment: the problem is because you are using `dirname()` this is for directory paths on a server NOT domain names or URL's. If you set `define("BASE_PATH", 'http://localhost:8888/');` you should not have the incorrect URL being produced. If you run `echo dirname('http://localhost:8888/');` you get http:!

Comment: do you want `define("BASE_PATH", "http://localhost:8888")`?

Comment: @msturdy i'm still developing. So for now that is what i want.

Comment: @ss_millionaire I mean: rather than `http://localhost...` ?  with the // after the colon

Comment: @msturdy Oh thats a typing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `define("BASE_PATH", "http://localhost:8888")` - I don't think you need to use `dirname()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works for me and this is dynamic too.

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].  '/emailtest'.'/verify.php?email=' . urlencode($email) . "&key=$encode";
```

Made use of the global `SERVER`.

Hope this works for you.